# How to use one tableview's button to automatically select the other tableview's button all

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a tableview that allows users to select items, primary is the main item, and each primary item contains a secondary list, I created a custom cell and also inserted the other tableview inside, as shown in the picture link below.

[Form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUsm.png)

Here's my ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PrimaryDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //This is my data
    var cardList = Card(userName: "Kevin", primaryList: [Card.Primary(primaryName: "Card1", secondaryList: [Card.Primary.Secondary(secondaryName: "Card1-1")]),Card.Primary(primaryName: "Card2", secondaryList: [Card.Primary.Secondary(secondaryName: "Card2-1"),Card.Primary.Secondary(secondaryName: "Card2-2")])])

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

@IBAction func enterAction(_ sender: Any) {
         //I hope here can print the result
         //How should I get the result from primaryList and secondaryList in Custom Cell ?
         print(cardList)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cardList.primaryList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.primaryLabel.text = cardList.primaryList[indexPath.row].primaryName
        cell.secondaryList = cardList.primaryList[indexPath.row].secondaryList
        cell.primaryIndex = indexPath.row
        cell.primaryDelegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func primaryIndex(index:Int) {
        //I use delegate to get index, but how to tell which secondaryList needs to be selected all?
        print("primaryIndex\(index)")
    }

}
```

Here's my Custom Cell, it includes the other tableview, that's why I feel complicated.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var primaryBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondaryBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var primaryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondaryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondaryTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondaryHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var primaryIndex:Int?
    var primaryDelegate:PrimaryDelegate?

    var secondaryList:[Card.Primary.Secondary]!{

        didSet{
            secondaryTableView.delegate = self
            secondaryTableView.dataSource = self
            secondaryTableView.reloadData()
            secondaryHeight.constant = secondaryTableView.contentSize.height
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return secondaryList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.secondaryLabel.text = secondaryList[indexPath.row].secondaryName
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func primaryBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !primaryBtn.isSelected
        primaryDelegate?.primaryIndex(index: primaryIndex!)
    }

    @IBAction func secondaryBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !secondaryBtn.isSelected

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

}
```

I hope it can be...

1.When the user selects the primary item, it can automatically help me select all the secondary items. However, the primary item can only be selected "one", and when the user selects the next primary item, the previous one needs to be canceled including all secondary items.

2.When the user press enterAction, it can print the data that user have chosen.I need to know what if user not choose primary, How many secondary list's item is selected.
I mean like result is Card1-1 and Card2-1, they only choose item in secondary list.

How should I tell custom cell's tableview to select all when I choose primary item, and how did custom cell know which primary is selected and needs to reload Data?

If need further information, please let me know, this selection rule make me really confused.Thanks

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this at your `primaryBtnAction` :

```
if sender.isSelected{
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
} else { //Deselect statement
    tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), animated: false)
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I've tried.but I use my own button, it didn't change. How should I change that ? and when I select primaryBtnAction Card2, card2-1 just flash once with gray color, and card2-2 is selected. and if I deselect Card2 the tableView.deselectRow seems not deselect.

Comment: if you don't mind, I can send you my example project. I really need to fix this problem.

Comment: primaryBtnAction is in  CustomTableViewCell

Comment: Did you try to add it didSelectRow func ?

Comment: Yes, but the tableView selection status not change.I'm just wondering whether I shouldn't use custom cell to add the other tableview, because you want me to get row and section, but my section alway is zero.

Comment: So, set your section zero. It doesn’t matter if you have only one section.